numpy giving wrong matrix results?
I am doing some matrix calculations and I am getting some wrong values.
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': lambda x: "{0:0.2f}".format(x)})

#deltaT
arr1 = np.array([[0, 0.01, 0, 0.1],
                 [0, -0.05, 0, 0],
                 [0.05, 0, -0.01, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0]])


#T1inv
arr2 = np.array([[0., 1., 0., -5],
                 [0, 0, 1, -2],
                 [1, 0, 0, -8],
                 [0, 0, 0, 1]])



# Multiply
arr3 = np.multiply(arr1, arr2)
print(arr3)

This is returning the wrong values. It should be returning:


I have tried a lot of different matrix multiplication techniques and none of them are returning the right value. Is the issue something with python and how it sees floating point values?

np.dot(arr2, arr1)

multiply is the elementwise or Hadamard product.  Also written as arr1 * arr2.

np.matmul and the @ operator are equivalents to np.dot.  Note that argument orders for this.  arr2@arr1 is what you show.  It would be nice if your screen shot showed what operation/command you used.

It seems you are looking for the matrix dot product rather than the multiplication product (dot vs multiply). I also noticed that in the code you provided the array order was flipped compared to the image which is important for these calculations. With these changes the code should look like this (notice arr2 is passed first in the dot product).
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': lambda x: "{0:0.2f}".format(x)})

#deltaT
arr1 = np.array([[0, 0.01, 0, 0.1],
                 [0, -0.05, 0, 0],
                 [0.05, 0, -0.01, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0]])


#T1inv
arr2 = np.array([[0., 1., 0., -5],
                 [0, 0, 1, -2],
                 [1, 0, 0, -8],
                 [0, 0, 0, 1]])



# Multiply
arr3 = np.dot(arr2, arr1)
print(arr3)

